# Possible to create a list template that includes the 'Default New Form'?

Tags: 2010, list-template

I added a content editor web part with some custom js into the 'Default New Form' for a list.  I then create a list template from that list, but when I create the new list it does not have the content editor that is in my 'Default New Form'.

Is there any way to include the 'Default New Form' in the list template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can. Is requires (as far as I know) a custom solution. You can create your list in a Visual Studio solution. In there, you have the options to specify your own NewForm.aspx, DispForm.aspx, etc. In those webpart pages you can add webparts, hide the default one, etc.

I believe this thread has what you need: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointcustomization/thread/5cb020a6-ab49-4368-9b97-894591ca1a9e/